# How to use app:items="@{viewModel.items}" attribute with RecyclerView, MVVM and data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

There is an `app:items=""` attribute for RecyclerView, how is this attribute used with MVVM and `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel`, not ViewModel that extends BaseObservable? `items` could be LiveData, List or ObservableArrayList, with which collection should it be used?

Comment: you need a BindingAdapter for that

Comment: Isn't it possible without @BindingAdapter?

Comment: no unfortunately it is not (AFAIK).

Comment: So we can't just directly bind a collection from ViewModel to RecyclerView. Do you have a link for an example, or tutorial?

Comment: `RV` doesn't deal with the dataset. It is its adapter.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. However, i thought i've seen somewhere that it was used as app:items=“@{viewModel.items}”, i will post source if it's ViewModel from arch and does not use @BindingAdapter. Thanks.

Comment: I would really love to see that.

Comment: where did you see those `app:items`? there is no such attribute in any support `recyclerview-v7` library

Comment: @pskink, i'm studying MVVM and data binding about a week. I'm searching for sub topics and i think i saw it was used in some github projecte, but i wasn't looking for this then, so i'm not sure. I will look for it specifically and post if it's used with ViewModel from arch library.

Comment: @pskink, yes there is `app:items` attribute for RecyclerView, i'm not sure how it's used with MVVM.

Comment: so where it is defined? what binding adapter implements it? [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/716ba89/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters) you have binding adapters for std android views, so where is that adapter for `RecyclerView`?

Comment: When you type items for RV in AS, it autocompletes it, however you should import architecture components in gradle. You should ask blackbelt how it's used with @BindingAdapter. I'm asking if it's possible to use with ViewModel.

Comment: i would bet you could get `items` in autocomplete for `TextView` too, so...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do see it for other views too in a project with arch components, otherwise it does no appear. I found the project https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter. I will look into this

Comment: https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/tree/master/bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview/src/main/java/me/tatarka/bindingcollectionadapter2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173950/discussion-between-thracian-and-pskink).